site can't be reached while containerize the frontend
I am having MERN stack web app in which two folders are there one is frontend and another is backend.
I created Dockerfile for the frontend
FROM node:20.10.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]

but when I open the browser at localhost:5173, showing me that site can't be reached
I tried to run the frontend manually without Dockerfile, in which I succeed to run in the browser
I run the following command for that:
npm i
npm run dev

did you tried to debug the container ? why it;s failing ? what's debugging steps you followed ?

I tried to check its logs but in that, it was showing:
2024-09-21 11:10:08
2024-09-21 11:10:08 > frontend@0.0.0 dev
2024-09-21 11:10:08 > vite
2024-09-21 11:10:08
2024-09-21 11:10:09
2024-09-21 11:10:09   VITE v5.4.7  ready in 809 ms
2024-09-21 11:10:09
2024-09-21 11:10:09   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
2024-09-21 11:10:09   ➜  Network: use --host to expose

The Vite dev server, like many dev servers, listens on the localhost-only interface, which in Docker is unreachable from outside its own container.  You need a --host option or equivalent code configuration to make it listen on all interfaces; the linked question has more details.
